# getting an error when doing code deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I'm running the following command to do a code deploy from jenkins to EC2 server

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name $APPNAME --s3-location bucket=$S3BUCKET,key=chefdeployment.zip,bundleType=zip --deployment-group-name $DEPLOYMENTGROUPNAME --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.HalfAtATime --description "Deploy" --region us-east-1 --profile $PROFILE --output text
```

I am getting the following error

```
A client error (InstanceIdRequiredException) occurred when calling the GetDeploymentInstance operation: Instance ID is Missing.
```

Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 1):

- InstanceIdRequiredException doesn't seem to be an exception that we throw when call create-deployment from CLI.
- The exception seems to be thrown when you call get-deployment-instance, and instanceId is required. Here is the doc for reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment-instance.html